# Resource level RBAC using ARM templates are not working

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

We were trying to create an automation pipeline in Azuredevops to assign roles in resource level for any kind of resources. and used below templae for that purpoe.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "roleDefinitionId": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "principalId": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "variables": {
      "roleAssignmentName": "[guid(parameters('principalId'), parameters('roleDefinitionID'), resourceGroup().id)]"
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/querypacks",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01-preview",
        "name": "[variables('roleAssignmentName')]",
        "properties": {
          "roleDefinitionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', parameters('roleDefinitionId'))]",
          "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

parameters.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": { 
       "roleDefinitionId": {
         "value": "#{roleDefinitionId}#"
       },
       "principalId": {
         "value": "#{principalId}#"
       }
                            
    } 
  }
```

Created Azuredevops Task to replace the parameters files "principalid" and "roledefinitionid" ids and when performing arm deployment group task with the updated templates, its failing.

Note: In my above example, i tried to assign the Contributor assignment only to a specific resource qpck-1 for a specific group.

is there any way to use same template to assign the roles at resource level for different kind of resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the template shows the resource `querypacks` explicitly, however, it should be parameterized

So you could change

```
 "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/querypacks"
```

to

```
"type": "[parameters('resourceType')]"
```

And in the parameter file add the following

```
    "resourceType": {
        "value": "#{resourceType}#"
    },
    "resourceName": {
        "value": "#{resourceName}#"
    }
```

Where the `resourceType` could be any type you need like `"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"`, and the `resourceName` cloud be the name of the VM like `ODS_VM`

And, by the way, it is better to provide the error message to be sure about the cause and the resolution.

Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are missing "scope" ?

for ex:

```
  {
  "scope": "[format('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/{0}', variables('mySBnameSpace'))]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
  "apiVersion": "2018-09-01-preview",
  "name": "[guid(variables('functionAppName'))]",
  "properties": {
    "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('ServiceBusReceiverRole')]",
    "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]"
  }
}
```